# How can I get keyboard events in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How can I get keyboard events in Google Spreadsheets?
I want to use this events in my script to format non-adjacent cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keyboard events for cells cannot be handled from apps script. you can only detect a cell change once it has beeb commited (user typed and pressed enter for example), which is not a keyboard event (its a range edit event)